# MySQL custom order by another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d865cf/2/1

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `letters` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `letter` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO `letters` (`id`, `letter`) VALUES
    (1, 'd'),
    (2, 'f'),
    (3, 'a'),
    (4, 'e'),
    (5, 'c'),
    (6, 'b');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sort` (
  `next` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prev` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`next`),
  UNIQUE KEY `prev` (`prev`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`next`) REFERENCES `letters` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO `sort` (`next`, `prev`) VALUES
    (3, NULL),
    (4, 1),
    (6, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (1, 5),
    (5, 6);
```

If I run now `select letter from letters` I get the order `d,f,a,e,c,b` but I want to get the alphabetical order `a,b,c,d,e,f` not with the help of `order by letter` but by using the `sort` table. If you look at the entries in `sort` table, a with `id=3` is first because `next=3 and prev is null` then b with `id=6` is second because `next=6 and prev=3`, then c with `id=5` is third because `next=5 and prev=6`, etc.

**How can I do a custom order using another table in MySQL?**

UPDATE

I did it and it may be the only way to do this in mysql:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `custom_select`()
begin

declare v_next int;
declare v_letter char(1);
declare v_count tinyint;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (id int,letter char(1),idx int AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY (idx));

select id,letter,count(*) into v_next,v_letter,v_count from letters where sort=0;
while v_next is not null do
  insert into temp(id,letter)values(v_next,v_letter);
  select id,letter,count(*) into v_next,v_letter,v_count from letters where sort=v_next;
end while;

select id,letter from temp order by idx;
end//
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `letters` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `letter` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sort` (`sort`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELETE FROM `letters`;

INSERT INTO `letters` (`id`, `letter`, `sort`) VALUES
  (1, 'd', 5),
  (2, 'f', 4),
  (3, 'a', 0),
  (4, 'e', 1),
  (5, 'c', 6),
  (6, 'b', 3);
```

Then i get `a,b,c,d,e,f` as expected with:

```
CALL custom_select
```

Comment: There is no way to do this with a single sql query in MySQL, since MySQL doesn't support recursive CTEs.

Comment: Then what about `order by some_sql_function()`? I opened for this. Inside a function could be all the necessary queries.

Comment: This would way too slow (I guess). This seems like a poor db design to me (although I don't know what the actual requirements are).

Comment: but why??? This calls for massive recursion if your table grows

Comment: Sorting this way is one of the options I have(the preferred one), the other one `is order by field(id,3,6,5,1,4,2)`. I'll have to decide later which is better, based on the advantages and disadvantages of each one of them.

Comment: Actually I am going to use a third option. I'l created a column `sort int(11)` in `letters` table then user `order by sort`. I'll update the `sort` column as necessary when the order needs to be changed.

Comment: I am still curious how a solution for this question will look like.

Comment: Who would want to write such a thing for you then have to defend it?

Comment: Indeed, from `order by letter` to this is just crazy, but we are living in a crazy world